# Bad answer from ResponseEntity<String>

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-mvc

Quick question.

I have a small Controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public class AuthenticationController
{
    public static final String LOGOUTED = "logouted";

    @Resource(name = "requireHardLoginEvaluator")
    private RequireHardLoginEvaluator requireHardLoginEvaluator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> status(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        if (!requireHardLoginEvaluator.evaluate(request, response))
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(LOGOUTED, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

When I'm debugging it, variable `new ResponseEntity<String>(AUTHENTICATED, HttpStatus.OK)` has good value ->`<200 OK,authenticated,{}>` but when I'm looking for it in my web browser, the response from /status is: "authenticated" with double quotes.

My question is: What causes that `authenticated` turns into a string of characters with double quotes like `"authenticated"` within `ResponseEntity` instance ?

Comment: i believe this `AUTHENTICATED` must be enum constant in some other class

Comment: Yes, sorry - I edited code to corret one

Comment: Is AUTHENTICATED a constant ?, in that cause what is it value ?

Comment: this is public static final String, but I made a mistake, this is not AUTHENTICATED but LOGOUTED, and value is = "logouted"

Comment: I think you could realized what was happening by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Because type you return is  String . Spring return with type you define `ResponseEntity<String>` here. You can return any type with set look like : `ResponseEntity<?>` .

Ps: Why you used @Controller instead of @RestController in your class ?

Comment: Ok, but in response in my web browser I have String but with double qoutes? Why and where `ResponseEntity` modify this?